# ¿Por qué solo funciona mi grabacion de audio en computadoras pero no en dispositivos moviles usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy usando las librerias de P5.js para hacer un Record & Save del audio que obtengo. Ese es mi codigo:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple Recorder.js demo with record, stop and pause</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="play" name="play">

</div>
    <!-- inserting these scripts at the end to be able to use all the elements in the DOM -->
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/08e7abd9/dist/recorder.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Y este es mi Javascript:

```
let mic, recorder, soundFile;

let state = 0; // mousePress will increment from Record, to Stop, to Play

function setup() {
document.getElementById('play').innerHTML = `<button type:"button" name="inicia">Inciar</button>` 

  // create an audio in
  mic = new p5.AudioIn();

  // users must manually enable their browser microphone for recording to work properly!
  mic.start();

  // create a sound recorder
  recorder = new p5.SoundRecorder();

  // connect the mic to the recorder
  recorder.setInput(mic);

  // create an empty sound file that we will use to playback the recording
  soundFile = new p5.SoundFile();
}

function mousePressed() {
  getAudioContext().resume()
  // use the '.enabled' boolean to make sure user enabled the mic (otherwise we'd record silence)
  if (state === 0 && mic.enabled) {
    // Tell recorder to record to a p5.SoundFile which we will use for playback
    recorder.record(soundFile);

document.getElementById('play').innerHTML = `<button type:"button" name="para">para</button>` 
    state++;
  } else if (state === 1) {
    recorder.stop(); // stop recorder, and send the result to soundFile
document.getElementById('play').innerHTML = `<button type:"button" name="guarda">guarda</button>` 
    state++;
  } else if (state === 2) {
    soundFile.play(); // play the result!
    saveSound(soundFile, 'mySound.wav'); // save file
    state++;
  }
}
```

Todo funciona correctamente en mi computadora pero al momento de usarlo en dispositivos mobiles no funciona. Estoy trabajando en mi entorno de localhost para poder hacerlo funcionar.

He tratado de buscar información pero no encuentro algo que permita solucionarlo. No sé si se trata de algún certificado SSL o simplemente me  hace falta agregar algo más a mi javascript.

¿Por qué sucede esto? ¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo? Gracias por toda su ayuda

Comment: te sugiero que revises el demo que es compatible con dispositivos mobiles: https://github.com/addpipe/simple-recorderjs-demo

Comment: Es posible que tenga que ver con los permisos de acceso a hardware.